# Compiling code too quickly gives errors

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

I have recently started coding with C++ and I have come across a little source of error which I think requires knowledge about computers that I don't have.

When I write a simple code (in Visual Studio Express 2013), let's say a "Hello World!" example, I *Build* and *Start Without Debugging* successfuly.
Then, when I edit my code to print the sum of two numbers for example, I get an error when I try to Build. I get this error:

> Error 1   error LNK1168: cannot open c:\users\name\documents\visual
>   studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Debug\ConsoleApplication4.exe
>   for writing

But if I wait for a bit and then re-attempt to Build, everything is fine.

I have also noticed this when I use g++ in the standard cmd module; if I try to complile a code under the same name (for the .exe file) I get an Access Denied error, but if I wait a bit I am allowed to do it.

My instincts tell me that the computer still has the .exe file running for a bit after I execute it, and it is not allowing me to overwrite it.

Comment: Yes, processes can take time to finish beyond the window closing.

Comment: Still, unless you're programming really quickly (which as a newbie seems unlikely), this delay should not be noticeable with such a simple program.

Comment: Change the sentence "computer still has the .exe file running" to "operating system still has a process whose memory space contains the executable image", and your observation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the process is still running and therefore the file is in use and write-locked.  It takes Windows a few tempo beats to clean everything up after you've terminated.

Comment: What is the typical "cleaning" time? Does it get bigger for larger code?

Comment: @PPG just guessing here but I'd say it's more a matter of how your machine is set up than anything else.

Comment: "It's because" is a bit strong language - the process running is just one possible reason. Mis-configured parallel builds can cause the problem too e.g. where two threads attempt to link the final .exe simultaneously. I've had that exact problem occur due to a bug in my SCons script.